# How to detect compound words / multiple words as one term.

Tags: nlp

Currently I am trying to detect nouns from texts. 
I would like to compound words / multiword expressions as one term. 
For example, I would like to detect "stock market" as one term, rather than "stock" and "market."

If you know any tools, related papers and so on, please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interested in collocations.
Hypothesis testing is a good way to start, plus it will give you nice insights from a statistical point of view.

Just follow the recipe here: http://nlp.stanford.edu/fsnlp/promo/colloc.pdf

There are also, rule-based, symbolic approaches, you should find easily by yourself.

Good luck.

Comment: This is a very helpful chapter, thank you. However this chapter only seems to treat bi-grams. Do you know similar (i.e. accessible) sources for building higher order collocations, e.g. 3-grams, 4-grams, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Many of compound words can be caught using illinois wikifier. See the demo here: 
http://cogcomp.cs.illinois.edu/demo/wikify/?id=25